# Calculate Columns

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'd like to perform simple calculations using `CellEndEdit` event. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellEndEdit

    Dim Total As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If IsDBNull(Total(0, e.RowIndex).Value) Then Exit Sub

    Total("C3", e.RowIndex).Value = Total("C1", e.RowIndex).Value + Total("C2", e.RowIndex).Value

End Sub
```

But when I entered 20 into both Column `C1` and `C2`, the `C3` is showing 2020 instead of 40. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the Type of `Total("C1", e.RowIndex).Value` is string, it's gonna concatenate them.
Try

```
Total("C3", e.RowIndex).Value = (((cint)Total("C1", e.RowIndex).Value) + ((cint(Total("C2", e.RowIndex).Value)).ToString()
```

To do an addition.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with strings the + operator is being used
 as a concat... Try;

```
Total("C3", e.RowIndex).Value = CInt(Total("C1", e.RowIndex).Value) + CInt(Total("C2", e.RowIndex))
```